# Make variables exist outside a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, scope, sh

I'm trying to make variables exits outside of a shell script without using source.
The variables are declared in shell script with

```
export varA=3
```

and I run the script with `./filename.sh`

I want

```
echo $varA
```

in the terminal to return 3 (i.e. the value of varA). So extend the scope of the variable to outside of the script

To sum up: how do I make the variables inside a shell script exist outside.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Without using "source"? You don't. Shells are designed so that this won't work. If you can't source the script itself for some reason then have it output another file that just has lines like VAR=some_value and then source *that*

Comment: Oh okey, so I cant use source on only one variable either? Does source only work on files?

Comment: Normally when you run a script it gets executed in a subshell, which means the runs in a separate environment from the terminal where you called it. (It copies over the environment variables when you start the script but doesn't copy them back even if the script changes them.) When you source a script, it runs the script in the same environment as your terminal (or wherever you call it from). So if you want a script to update your environment variables you have to source it.

Comment: Running bash scripts doesn't work like, say, trying to call a function in most programming languages. If you try to make it like that your life will be pain. If you just want to return a value then have the script print it to standard output and put the output in a variable.

Comment: Also, you would never need to use "source" on a variable. You just set the variable. The concept is only applicable to running scripts. Not sourced: different environment. Source: same environment.

Comment: If `varA` was defined and equal `3`, `export $varA` would be weird. What do you expect from exporting a numeric literal? Did you mean `echo $varA`?

Comment: eh yeah I wrote wrong, can edit it to be correct

Comment: If sourcing your script is not an option you could also apply the same strategy as, e.g., `ssh-agent`: echo a command that does what you want, and `eval` it from the top-level shell. So, your script would contain `echo "export varA=3"`. And you would use it from the top-level with: `eval "$(./filename.sh)"`.

Comment: nice, I will try that too

Comment: Another perspective: your file doesn't contain a variable. It contains code that *creates* a variable; variables only exist in memory. With that in mind, executing a script `(./filename.sh)` makes that code run in a *separate* process, while `source ./filename.sh` makes the code run in the *current* process.

Answer (score 2):

You can run your script on this way:

```
. ./filename.sh
```

This mean when run it will not spawn new shell but run it in current. And variables you set in your script will be available in your shell. This is kind of "source" as mentioned in comments.